# how to access a different module in multi target application

Tags: node.js, sapui5, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

I'm new to cloud foundry, so I'm not sure, if my thoughts and plans are right. Maybe someone can explain or discuss it with me.

***What I want to do:***
Implement a MTA (Multitarget Application) with a **a html5-module as frontend** and a **nodeJS-module as backend**. Furthermore there should be a **mongodb instance**, which will be accessed from the nodejs-module. Later it should also get multitenant.

***What I already did:***
I implemented a simple nodejs-app and connected it to the db. Persisting and calling data with rest works already fine. I implemented a simple sapui5 app, which consumes data from the db with ajax. For now, the node startscript is in the html5 module, so it works somehow. But now I want to separate the modules.
So I created a mta-project with the two modules in webide and imported the two apps.

***What I expect to do for it:***
For now, I have an approuter, which is in my **nodejs-module**, but I can not access the webapp folder in the **html5-module** from here: **file not found error: /home/vcap/app//**. Is there a possibility to access the webapp-folder in another module over the path **"/home/vcap/app/"**? Or can I lookup the app-directory anywhere?

I have read, that an approuter-module (nodejs) can be needed, but I don't know exactly what it does. I think it serves the index.html file when opening the url of the whole app?

Comment: If your html5-module runs in the clients browser, then it will not be able to access `/var/vcap/app`, because that resides on the server. What you need is for your server to expose any files that live on the server side over HTTP so that your client can access them. Often times a server side app will do something like `http://example.com/static/...` which is a path where all the static files can be found. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure, if I understand it right. Do I have to put the webapp folder with my views in the node-module, which creates my server with express? But what would then be the sense of a MTA and the separation of the modules? Or do I have to create an extra node-module which serves statically the static files somehow?